# Fancybox pulling up lightbox effect for video, but nothing plays

Tags: jquery, video, fancybox, screen, lightbox

I have the picture that pulls up, and when I click on it, it's supposed to pull up a light box, which it does, but nothing plays in the frame. It's just white.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".fancyYoutube").fancybox({
             'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
            'padding' : 0,
            'autoScale' : false,
           'transitionOut' : 'fade',
           'width' : 680,
           'height' : 495,
           'type' : 'swf'
       });

        if(location.hash) {
            $(location.hash).click();
        }

    });


</script>
```

```
<a class="fancyYoutube" rel="group" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29tFKSylaGE"><img src="images/Bronco copy.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: what version of fancybox? ... if using v1.3.4 check http://fancybox.net/blog No. 4

Comment: Latest version, just downloaded it from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license

Comment: Then, on the same page look for Extended functionality ==> Media helper and follow the examples at html and javascript **tabs** (don't forget to include the media helpers js file)

Comment: followed everything in the media helper, now I'm getting a "The file or directory could not be found." error, but everything looks almost exactly like the examples.                                     <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({
  openEffect  : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none',
  helpers : {
   media : {}
  }
 });
});
</script>


</head>



<body>

<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">Youtube</a>

<a class="fancybox" href="http://vimeo.com/36031564">Vimeo</a>

</body>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fancybox v2.x, you could use the `media helper` so having this html (as per your comment):

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">Youtube</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="http://vimeo.com/36031564">Vimeo</a>
```

**NOTE** : you don't add a semicolon `;` at the end of the `<a>` tag (it's not javascript)

Then you could use this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        helpers: {
            media: {}
        }
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n8bcj803/)**